# Default Samsung S4 messsenger application name

Tags: samsung, sms, mms

I disabled all the default samsung apps on my S4. I was using google messenger. Now I want to revert back to the samsung apps. I need to go into all apps menu and find the default samsung messenger one to enabled it but I can not find it.

What is the name of the default samsung s4 messenger application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to settings>applications>application manager and go to disabled apps tab where you see all your disabled apps.

P.S App you searching for, called **Messenger**

Comment: Its actually called "Messaging", but going to disabled apps solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean ChatOn?
But this messenger by Samsung was shut down in 2015.
There were anyway only few people using it.
Try best Signal, you even can call with it and it is encrypted and OpenSource.

Comment: I mean the default Samsung SMS app...not a data messenger